# Rounding large decimals to nearest decimals

Tags: javascript, rounding

So I have a function that rounds to certain decimal scales

```
const roundNumber = (num, scale) => {
   let n = num
   switch(scale){
    case 0.50:
        n = (Math.ceil(num*2)/2).toFixed(2)
    break;
    case 0.25:
        n = (Math.ceil(num*4)/4).toFixed(2)
    break;
    case 0.20:
        n = (Math.ceil(num*5)/5).toFixed(2)
    break;
    case 0.10:
        n =  (Math.ceil(num*10)/10).toFixed(2)
    break;
    case 0.05:
        n = (Math.ceil(num*20)/20).toFixed(2)
    break;
  }

  return n
}
```

How would I adapt this to round to even smaller amounts such as...

```
  0.000001, 0.000025, 0.000050, 0.0001,0.00025, 0.00050, 0.001 etc etc
```

So example.

```
  0.48675387
```

I want to be able to output any of these amounts from this one number

```
 0.48675000
 0.48680000
 0.48700000
 0.49000000
 0.50000000
```

Do I need to use a Big Number library for this?  I can't think of how I would do this.

EDIT:  Ive updated this with a table of values of inputs and outputs so you can see what I want to achieve.  I basically want the number to snap to certain values, based on how close they are to them.  Like normal rounding, but slightly different.

```
      Scale      Number         Output
      0.00025    0.45341000     0.45350
      0.0025     0.45341000     0.4525 (closer to 0.4525 than 0.4550
      0.005      0.45341000     0.455
      0.01       0.45341000     0.45
```

See how the values differ if I simply just use toPrecision or toFixed

```
      Number         Output
      0.45341000     0.45341
      0.45341000     0.4534
      0.45341000     0.453
      0.45341000     0.45
```

Comment: Could you provide some more specific input/output combinations? A brief table of inputs and outputs would help clarify the problem.

Comment: Ive provided a table to show desired inputs and outputs

Comment: I wonder if you will get better answers on https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty but I'll put it down here and maybe come back to refine it. This should get you there though. *Update: removed toPrecision early in the function since we're not using normal rounding.*

```
   function roundTo(num, scale) {
        let arr, places, ref, lastx, remainder, thenum
        arr = scale.toString().split(".")
        places = arr[1].length; // get number decimal places
        num = Number(num).toFixed(places); // get our starting number in the right format
        ref=scale * Math.pow(10, places); // get our scale to the right format
        lastx = Number(num.toString().substr(-(ref.toString().length))) // get the scale increment
        remainder  = lastx%ref; // modulus
        if (remainder>=ref/2) thenum= Number((ref-remainder)*Math.pow(.1, places)) // if we need to add an amt
        else thenum = Number(remainder*Math.pow(.1, places)) * -1 ; // if we need to substract an amt
        thenum = thenum.toFixed(places) // fix our value
//        console.log(places,num,ref,lastx,remainder,thenum);

        num=(Number(num) + Number(thenum)).toFixed(places) // final calculation
        return num;
    }


console.log(roundTo(0.8946, 0.001));
console.log(roundTo(1.8946, 0.001));
```

Comment: Ive updated the answer with an input/output table to show what I mean.  I kinda want the rounding to snap to certain values.

Comment: @Kylie - check the updated answer out and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah I ended up solving it simlarly.  Thanks for the effort though

Comment: This doesnt work for numbers larger than 1 right?  example 0.8946 with scale 0.001 gives me  0.895.  But 1.8946 gives me 1.89

Comment: Updated - should be ok

Answer (score 1):

Use `Number.prototype.toPrecision()`

```
let n  =   0.48675387

n.toPrecision(5)
"0.48675"
n.toPrecision(4)
"0.4868"
n.toPrecision(3)
"0.487"
n.toPrecision(2)
"0.49"
n.toPrecision(1)
"0.5"
```

Comment: I know I can use this and .toFixed(n) to achieve the rounding.  But I want the rounding to snap to certain intervals.  Its kinda hard to explain what I mean.  But for example, if my number is 0.45221000, and my chosen scale is 0.005, I want the number to output 0.450, but if I do toPrecision(3), or toFixed(3), I get 0.452, If I do toPrecision(2), I get the correct output, but then if the number was 0.45351000, then I want 0.455, and using precision(2), and precision(3), doesnt give me what I want.

Comment: I want it to snap to certain values

Comment: See my input/output table to see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I think the algorithm you're describing is:

1. divide the number by the scale
2. round that result to get an integer
3. multiply the scale by the resulting integer

In other words: "If I split this number into chunks of size `scale`, then add one more chunk if the remainder is more than half of the `scale` amount, and then put the chunks back together, what is the sum?"

```js
function roundTo(scale, number) {
  return Math.round(number / scale) * scale;
}
```

```js
function roundTo(scale, number) {
  return Math.round(number / scale) * scale;
}

const examples = [
  { scale: 0.00025, number: 0.45341000, expected: 0.45350 },
  { scale: 0.0025,  number: 0.45341000, expected: 0.4525 },
  { scale: 0.005,   number: 0.45341000, expected: 0.455 },
  { scale: 0.01,    number: 0.45341000, expected: 0.45 },
]

examples.forEach(({ scale, number, expected }) => {
  const actual = roundTo(scale, number);
  const isExpectedResult = actual === expected ? '✅' : '❌';
  console.log({ scale, number, expected, actual, isExpectedResult });
});
```

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  I ended up solving it but its quite un-elegant.  If you'd like to take a stab at a prettier version that would be great lol

Comment: Done  

`Math.round(number / scale) * scale`